# Excel VBA - copying data from variable named sheets to specific sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have code for 4 "transfer" procedures. What I wanted to do is something similar to **copy and paste to the last active cell in the column**. The process works fine but is overlapping each other.

Another problem I'm encountering is that I can't seem to make the code work for **Sheets 1 to 10**. I need to make it `i + 3` to make it work but it doesn't work properly. I'm still missing 3 Sheets. Making it only `1 to 7`.

Code is as follows:

```
Sub transfer_exp()

Dim ws As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim orow As Integer
Dim lrow As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim ewt As Range
Dim vat As Range
Dim vatx As Range

n = Sheets("Start").Range("c24").Value + 3

If n > 0 Then
    For i = 3 To n

        Dim desrow As Integer
        desrow = i - 1
        rng = Range("AA11:AA40")
        Set sheet = Sheets(i)
        lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Dim origcol As Integer
        origcol = 1

        Dim origrow As Integer
        origrow = 11

            For Each c In sheet.Range("AA11:AA40")
                If c > 0 Then

                    'Header lines
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 1).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(3, 3).Value 'Vendor
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 2).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(2, 3).Value 'Transaction Date
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 3).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(4, 3).Value 'RefNumber
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 4).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(5, 3).Value 'Bill Due
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 5).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(6, 3).Value 'Terms
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 6).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(7, 3).Value 'Memo

                    'Expense lines
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 7).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(origrow, 5).Value 'Expenses Account
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 8).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(origrow, 15).Value 'Expenses Amount
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 9).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(origrow, 22).Value 'Expenses Memo
                    Sheets("OFFLIMITS").Cells(lrow, 10).Value = Sheets(i).Cells(origrow, 7).Value 'Expenses Class

                    'row locators
                    lrow = lrow + 1
                    origrow = origrow + 1
                End If
            Next c
    Next i

End If

End Sub
```

This code is very identical to the next one that tends to overlap the results. Except of course in some details. But 90% identical when it comes to process flow. I'd like to know what am I missing. Or any errors I'm committing that makes the data in destination cells overlap. Thanks in advance guys. More power. :)

Comment: You can firstly hardcode your Header lines, so instead of `Sheets(i).Cells(3,3).Value` just place `"Vendor"`  Also there are some variables that you declare and then don't use: `origcol` and `desrow` If you step through the code you should see wether or not the lrow increments as should be, and then avoids the overlap.

Comment: Please be a little more specific. The "OFFLIMITS" worksheet has to be populated with values found in the n sheets you wish to loop over. Do these values have to be put underneath each other, so you have 1 sheet with all values from the others?
And what do you exactly mean by "overlap"? That you're overwriting the previously "pasted" values, or...? 
In any case I'm not sure what the required behavior is and what the other 4 macro's are supposed to do differently than your sample code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RikSportel, underneath each other - if that means values will be on row 1, then row 2 then 3...4... and so on, yes. I have 10 sheets which will be the sources. example, data from sheet 1 will be on OFFLIMITS rows 1 to 10, then sheet 2 will be on 11 and so on. The data from the sources are not uniform so what I wanted was for them to be at the next blank row. But what happens is part of the code is working, not overlapping then suddenly, part is overlapping (overwriting the other data). The only difference that the other 3 macros have is the cell references from the source sheet.

Comment: @Luuklag, I'll definitely check that out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Are there any more sheets than these 10 + "Offlimits"? If not, do the source sheets have specific names?

Comment: Make those numbers into an array.  For example, `Dim arr As Variant; arr = Array(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 15, 22, 7)`